# How do I show a changing value in a log?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have an ASP.NET Core application and I do not know what to do next. Note - I use Visual Studio 2019.

I have a progress for a image download. I would like to know if my code works well and outputs the correct value (if you notice something or if there is a better solution you are welcome to inform me).
But I don't want to constantly debug all the steps through the code (which would take a lot of time at this point).

So my idea was to keep the `progress` somewhere (maybe in a console log), so I can watch it all the time.

**What did I try?**

I've added a simple `Console.WriteLine (progress)` into my method, but I see no console. Then I tried it with the `Command Window` and `>? progress`, but it only outputs the value if the breakpoint is set,
which leads to the same problem again.

What would I have to adjust so I can see the progress in a log?

**Here is my code:**

```
while(...)
{
    if (ExpectedStreamSize.HasValue && _configSize.HasValue)
    {
        var expected = ExpectedStreamSize + _configSize.Value;
        var progress = _stream.ReadPosition / (float) expected;
        var limitedProgress = progress > 1 ? 1 : progress;

        var epsilon = 0.001;
        if (!_lastReportedProgress.HasValue || _lastReportedProgress.Value + epsilon < limitedProgress)
            _onProgressChanged?.Invoke(limitedProgress);

        _lastReportedProgress = limitedProgress;
        Console.WriteLine(progress);     // I setted my breakpoint in here
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you look for the console output in the Output window of VS? Debug\Windows\Output

Comment: @StephenKennedy yes, I also looked there - that was my actual plan, but unfortunately I find no values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try logging to file. This way you can debug even in release mode or when running the executable outside of Visual Studio.

```
public void LogToFile(string text)
{
    string path = @"c:\temp\MyTest.txt";

    string appendText = text + Environment.NewLine;
    File.AppendAllText(path, appendText);
}
```

Comment: That worked for the first time and gave me a result thank you.
In a console edition it would be better for the use case but that fits!

Answer (score 0):

While debugging, right click on the variable, choose "add watch". You will see it's value bellow in the watches window.

Comment: I have already tried that, but then I do have to debug the individual steps again or am I wrong here?